# When inserting to a table, do I have to define a nullable parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

This is the query I have to create a table and insert a record. I have some fields that are nullable here. If I want to create an insert statement do I have to define a value for the nullable parameters placeholder? For example, in my insert statement I'm defining active having an ID of 1. The last 4 nullable columns insertDt, InsertPartyId, UpdateDt, UpdatePartId are all empty for this record statement insert. Is this fine and the proper way of creating an insert with nullables?

![Me getting ready to query said statement.][1]

```
Create Table RecognitionStatusDomain
Id integer,
Description nvarchar(100),
InsertDt DateTime,
InsertPartyId integer,
UpdateDt DateTime,
UpdatePartId integer);

Insert into RecognitionStatusDomain (Description)
(Values 1, 'Active', Null);
```

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Please don't link to images. Copy and paste the code here. As to nullable columns, sure, just don't mention them in the insert statement or set them null explicitly: `insert into recognationstatusdomain (id, description) values (1, 'active')` or `insert into recognationstatusdomain (id, description, insertdt, insertpartyid, updatedt, updatepartyid) values (1, 'active', null, null, null, null)`.

Comment: Usually you'd use some auto incrementing type for IDs, if your DBMS supports that. And insert and update times should probably be set by a default value for the column or by a trigger.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten for the tip. I'm actually new to this and am just following my supervisors instructions per word. I don't wanna list anything he hasn't deemed himself. I will bring these up though. I think they had other descriptions besides active and inactive,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null fields are any columns that are **nullable**.

They are specified in the table column definition as "null" or "not null". If they are nullable you can insert nulls to the column. These nulls represent an "unkown" state. INSERT INTO TABLE (myNullableCol) VALUES (NULL) as you have in your image works perfectly fine.

If you try to insert null into a column that doesn't allow it, SQL will fail and show you an error.

Answer (score 2):

So what I think you're asking is can you update columns that are defined as null later. The answer is yes. For your situation you could create the table:

```
create table RecognitionStstusDomain
(
Id int not null
,Description nvarchar(100) not null
,InsertDt datetime
,InsertPartyId int
,UpdateDt datetime
,UpdatePartyId int
);

insert into recognitionststusdomain (Id, Description)
values (1, 'active');
```

Again, from what I can understand you are wanting Id and Description to be *not null* since you know what values you want them to be and want to update the others later.

I defined the *Id* and *Description* columns as *not null* which will make you enter a value in those fields. The rest of the columns allow nulls and you will be able to update later. You don't have to define the rest of the values as null they will just show *null* with no input.

here is a link showing what I did and what the results will be http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8da61/1/0

Answer (score 1):

OK, first things first. You actually can perform the row insertion as you pretend to. Nothing will prevent you from inserting nulls in the whole row if you wanted to.

Now, the practical thing. How are you going to retrieve that row (later in life) in order to (for example) add more information to it? You'll need a key.

So, to make it practical, add a key to that table. Since you don't want to specify its value, use an auto-generated key (auto increment, or identity by default/always). This way you will be able to identify the rows you inserted inequivocally.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to insert some value to a column you can leave in your insert statement or you can just put NULL to that column.

```
insert into recognationstatusdomain (id, description) values (1, 'active');
```

OR

```
insert into recognationstatusdomain (id, description, insertDt, insertPartyId, updateDt, updatePartyId) values (1, 'active', null, null, null, null);
```

OR

```
insert into recognationstatusdomain values (1, 'active', null, null, null, null);
```

If you assign any column a primary key or assign a constraint NOT NULL then you can't insert NULL values to that column.

```
Create Table Table_Name(id int NOT NULL, Name varchar(10))
Insert into Table_Name (id,Name) values(NULL,'Some_Name') --Give you an error
```